Does shap's gradientexplainer take in a tensorflow function or a model?
I'm using tensorflow 2 trying to call the gradientexplainer. I'm looking at the docs and it states the following:
Note that for TensowFlow 2 you must pass a tensorflow function, not a tuple of input/output tensors
However it seems that you need to pass in your model directly, you can't pass a tensorflow function.
My model expects a dictionary instead of a nparray or dataframe, so I am attempting to call gradientexplainer like so:
@tf.function
def model_fcn(data):
    feed_dict = {k: tf.convert_to_tensor(data[:, i:i+1]) for i, k in enumerate(feature_keys)}
    return model(feed_dict)
gradientexplainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model_fcn, X)

However I get this error: ValueError: <class tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function.polymorphic_function.Function'> is not currently a supported model type!
Just wondering if you can pass in a function to gradientexplainer or if it has to be the keras model

The docs clearly say "For TensorFlow this can be a model object, or a pair of TensorFlow tensors (or a list and a tensor) that specifies the input and output of the model to be explained. Note that for TensowFlow 2 you must pass a tensorflow function, not a tuple of input/output tensors)." So it has to be a model object (which also acts as a callable function).

Interesting, so a tensorflow function in this case is basically a model object that's callable. I ask because for Tensorflow 1 it says it can be a model object, but then it says it's a tensorflow function.

It's honestly bad wording. But at first it says "model object or pair of tensors", but then excludes the pair of tensors for TF 2. So that only leaves "model object". As you rightly stated, "Tensorflow function" covers much more than just models. I had a quick look at the source code, and it indeeds checks if the "model" argument is one of several keras Model subclasses, and if not, it raises this error. So it has to be an actual Keras Model.
